# Right click when git is installed

Tags: git, windows-8

When I install git on a fresh copy of Windows 8.1 embedded, right clicking on folders takes 3-4 seconds. If I remove git, right clicking takes the normal amount of time again.

How can I reduce the time it takes to right click on folders with git installed?

Comment: Git meaning Git Extensions? Do you really need Git in the context menu?

Comment: git meaning only git without extentions. If removing the context menu solves this problem that Right Click is normal state, I can relinquish the context menu. P.S. This problem has another promblem that git bash'commends are slow. :(